# Android email and password authencitation app crashes

Tags: java, android, firebase, crash

When an `Activity` start with `Firebase` email and password authentication app get crashed

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: company.pawelzielinski.drdtr, PID: 18455
>                     java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Interface com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeuq implemented by class com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is inaccessible (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth' appears in /data/app/company.pawelzielinski.drdtr-9wLtUa_yKNZf-NsqQCRFzw==/base.apk)
>                         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>                         at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453)
>                         at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:378)
>                         at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(SourceFile:734)
>                         at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zze(SourceFile:705)
>                         at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(SourceFile:328)
>                         at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(SourceFile:294)
>                         at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(SourceFile:281)
>                         at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(SourceFile:37)
>                         at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1925)
>                         at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1900)
>                         at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(SourceFile:31)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6572)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6127)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6037)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1764)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)

```
package company.pawelzielinski.drdtr;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class register_with_firebase extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText email,password;
    Button registerButton;
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_with_firebase);

        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email_firebase_register);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_firebase_register);
        registerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register_button);


        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email_string = email.getText().toString();
                String password_string = password.getText().toString();

                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email_string)){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please fill in the required fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password_string)){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please fill in the required fields",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                if(password_string.length()<7){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Password must be at least 6 characters",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email_string,password_string)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),register_window.class));
                                    finish();
                                }
                                else{
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"E-mail or password is wrong",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
        });


        if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null){
           startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),main_menu_in_game.class));
        }
    }
}
```

> dependencies {
>       implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
>
> ```
> implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
> implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
> implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc02'
> implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
> implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
> implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
> implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
> implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
> implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:11.8.0'
> testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
>
> implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
> implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.1'
> androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
> androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
> implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
> ```
>
> } apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
>
> buildscript {
>
> ```
> repositories {
>     google()
>     jcenter()
> }
> dependencies {
>     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
>     classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
>
>
>     // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
>     // in the individual module build.gradle files
>     classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
> } }
> ```
>
> allprojects {
>       repositories {
>           google()
>           jcenter()
>       } }
>
> task clean(type: Delete) {
>       delete rootProject.buildDir }

Comment: Post your code also

Comment: Update your dependencies.

Comment: @AnisurRahmanTonu code added

Comment: @Paweł Zieliński  show your build.gradle please

Comment: @Paweł Zieliński use same version of all dependency. you have mixed up 16.0.1 and 11.6.0 and 11.8.0
also remove redundant classpath for google service

Comment: Also, please check Java code style. `class register_with_firebase` O_o
[Google style](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html)

Comment: @AnisurRahmanTonu now im getting this:
The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to 16.0.1. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    buildscript {

        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'


            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }


    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

Add dependency as follows

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.4'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.3'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.1'
```

Comment: InnerClass annotations are missing corresponding EnclosingMember annotations. Such InnerClass annotations are ignored.
Message{kind=WARNING, text=InnerClass annotations are missing corresponding EnclosingMember annotations. Such InnerClass annotations are ignored., sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}

Comment: Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file. Try supplying a main-dex list.
# methods: 83198 > 65536
Message{kind=ERROR, text=Cannot fit requested classes in a single dex file. Try supplying a main-dex list.
# methods: 83198 > 65536, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}

Comment: enable multidex support

Comment: android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    ...
}

implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

Comment: never mind working fine! Thank you very much for your time <3